# Junction table with additional columns in EF4 CTP4 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef4-code-only

Given this sql schema:

```
create table [dbo].[Courses_Students] (
    [DummyColumn] [int] null,
    [CourseId] [int] not null,
    [StudentId] [int] not null,
    primary key ([CourseId], [StudentId])
);
```

How do I define the composite primary key and the additional columns in the `EntityConfiguration`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare a class `Courses_Students`

```
public class Courses_Students
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int DummyColumn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The Key on CourseId, is to prevent a compilation error, you will override it next.

Then, in your DbContext class, you override OnModelCreating like so :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Courses_Students>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.CourseId, e.StudentId })
        .MapSingleType()
        .ToTable("Courses_Students");
}
```

Comment: But i was expecting to have actually navigation properties in the Courses_Students class. At least, that's what I get when generating the model with the EF designer.